# Something is eating my vegetables - what is it?

Tags: vegetables, raised-beds, rodents, leaf-vegetables

I have a raised bed where I grow vegetables (Kale, tomatoes, cucumbers, beets, carrots, melons, etc.).  Something comes by at nights and eats some of the fruits and vegetables, in particular the melons.  How do I figure out what is sharing my food?  I have a net covering the plants so I don't think it is birds so it is either a mouse or squirrels or something else.  They seem to be getting through the net or under the net.  I live in the San Francisco Bay Area

[image]

Comment: picture of damage could help... if you suspect a vertebrate pest, you could put out a game camera

Comment: Do you have voles around?

Comment: @grady will try to post pictures next time

Comment: @graham what is a vole?

Comment: Like a mouse, they are tiny enough to go through small netting

Comment: @JStorage [Wikipedia on voles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vole)

Comment: I have not seen any and that is the issue.  What is eating my vegetables and fruits?  How do I find out so I can do something about it?  What does a game camera do?  Link would be great

Comment: could just be snail/slugs

Comment: an example game camera http://www.amazon.com/Moultrie-Game-Glow-Camera-Green/dp/B00T34P34M

Comment: I have not seen any snails or slugs.  Will keep looking tho.  Thanks for the pointer to the camera.

Comment: @grady - are you using this camera in your garden and happy with the results?  Also, does t his camera scare away the rodents or just takes pictures?  If it has some time of motion detection and can flash a light, that may serve the purpose

Comment: no I haven't ever used a camera like this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could easily be slugs; to find out you need to catch them. Go out after dark with a flashlight and look at the leaves, especially on nights after rain or when it is a bit moist. If that is the problem crushed eggshells spread around the plants will help.

Comment: That was it. I found a slug under one of the cover crop leaves when I was removing them.